# Listing only pandas rows that match a criteria based on function output

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a line defined by `mx+b`, where `m,b` are variables acquired from `np.linalg.lstsq`.

Also have created a function called distance defined as:

```
def distance(x0, y0, slope, yintercept):
    """Returns the euclidean distance between a line and
    a point"""
    return abs(slope*x0-y0+yintercept)/(slope**2+1)**.5
```

For convenience I have created a vectorized form as in:

`vdistance = np.vectorize(distance,otypes=[np.float])`

I have a pandas array called `spiral` that contains a bunch of points over a irregular spiral. This pandas dataframe has three fields (among others): `spiral.t , spiral.x, spiral.y`, where `t` is the a increasing value on time and `x,y` are the coordinates of spiral on cartesian plane (rect coordinates).

Therefore for each `spiral.x,spiral.y` pair I have a correspondent `spiral.t`.

I can easily calculate the distance from each point on spiral to that line defined on start with

`distance(spiral.x, spiral.y, m, b)`

Since is a pandas dataframe, when I call `spiral.x` I got the whole column. There fore I did:

```
x0 = np.array(spiral.x)
y0 = np.array(spiral.y)

dist=vdistance(x0,y0,m,b)
```

And I have a `np.array dist` with all distances. With that I could get the `indexes <= K`, where `K` is a reasonable distance to me, near enough to the line (in this case 250) with:

```
near = np.where(dist <= 250)
```

And now for every value in near I can iterate over the spiral retrieving the correct `t`s. (because the t doesn't grows in the same rate).

```
ts=[]
for i in near:
    ts += [ spiral.t[i] ]
```

My question is how do this in a single shot with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use df.apply() to iterate over rows and access multiple columns for a function.

`df[df.apply(distance, axis=1)]`

axis=1 here tells apply to iterate over rows. df.apply() will iterate over columns if axis=0. The result of this statement is a dataframe, which is a subset of `df` with fewer rows.

To make this work, your `distance` function should return a boolean value. The logic of this function could be:

```
def distance(row):
    dist = compute_dist(row['x'], row['y'])
    if dist < 250:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Ok I. Have created a `distance` function that is pandas aware that   `return abs(slope*row['x']-row['y']+yintercept)/(slope**2+1)**.5`. With that I now call `spiral['distance']=spiral.apply(distance,args=(m,b),axis=1)`. Since I'm running a VERY old version of pandas (0.8.0), (I can't update). I'm looking a way to run the .where clause, since where isn't implemented on pandas 0.8.0.

Comment: I can run `spiral['distance'] < 250`, that returns me a `pandas.Series` with `index Bool`, but don't know how to apply it to the existing dataframe since  `pandas.DataFrame.loc` is also not implemented in `0.8.0`.. what a hell.

Comment: `spiral[spiral.distance < 250]` returns me a "view"  of data that I want.

Comment: Hi @Lin, the return of this statement df[df.apply(distance, axis=1)] is a dataframe, which is a subset of the original dataframe with fewer rows. If you can make your distance function to return a boolean, you will save a lot of time. The logic will be like if the distance < 250, return True, else return False.